# Unexpected auto-route after adding a new /29-Net

Tags: linux-networking, route, interface, debian-squeeze

I added a new Network to a Debian 6.0.1 x86_64 Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64 Server with this configuration in the interfaces:

```
allow-hotplug eth2
iface eth2 inet static
  address 172.251.1.86
  netmask 255.255.255.248
  network 172.251.1.80    #(tried with and without)
  broadcast 172.251.1.87  #(tried with and without)
```

The other interfaces are classical, static declarations. bridge-utils is installed but no br-device is enabled.

After ifup:

```
2: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:1f:13:6d:36:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.251.1.86 peer 172.251.1.1/29 brd 172.251.1.87 scope global eth2
    inet6 fe80::e61f:13ff:fe6d:3698/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I expect this route to be added automatically:

```
...
172.251.1.80    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth2
...
```

But this route is added:

```
...
172.251.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth2
...
```

Of course I can add some up-lines to the interfaces file to fix the routes. I'm just wondering if I am missing something. Maybe some cache to flush, a typo I am missing since hours, or just a misunderstanding.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is related to the `peer 172.251.1.1/29` shown in the `ip addr` output, though there is nothing in the configurations you have shown which indicate where this is coming from.

Check through your configurations for references to `172.251.1.1/29` as this will likely then point you to the ultimate source of your problem.